# How do I create unique id:s for jquery dialogs generated by php in a list?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with jquery dialogs. When using them just hardcoded on to a button they work just fine. But when I run through a vector in php to generate some search results, my more info button stops working. The first option will generate a dialog when pressed, the content in it however is wrong. List items after this one will not show a dialog popup and if I press on a button when scrolled down it jumps up to the first item.

My guess is that this behavior is generated due to multiple buttons with the same id. This is the first homepage I've made and I do not really know how to tackle this problem.

Some code:

```
PHP part:

$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

  ...yadayada...
  <a style="position:relative;left:600px;top:-40px;" href="#" id="dialog_link" onmouseover="document.rollover.src=button2.src" onmouseout="document.rollover.src=button1.src" >
    <img src="images/search/info_btn_unsel.png" border="0" name="rollover" />
  </a>
</div>
</div>
}

JavaScript part:

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Dialog           
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      buttons: {
        "Ok": function() { 
          $(this).dialog("close"); 
        }, 
      }
    });

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

complete file can be found here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10627595/timeseek_result.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each dialog box has information in it unique to each row of search results, then each dialog needs its own unique id. Also, each dialog box content needs php variables that are unique for each row.

After reading your question and looking at your code, this appears to be the case. If I am correct, then solving your problem will be a little more involved than changing the id's to classes.

Comment: Switching from id:s to classes made the popup show, but as you say there will be more to it than that :)

I guess it's rather easy to give the node a unique id, but how do I get the javascript part to fetch this id?

Comment: Many, many thanks jen. This was exactly what i needed!
It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

You must **never** have repeated ids, this was causing the problem. Use a class instead

So you'd have:

```
<a class="dialog_link" ... >
```

And your jquery code would be:

```
$('.dialog_link').click(function(){ //Note the . instead of #
   $('#dialog').dialog('open'); //The same code
   return false; //The same code
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, that made the popup show but the larger problem remains. The info is the same in all of the popups and the problem is still id:s that need to be unique. Setting it to a unique value is no problem. The problem is fetching it.

Comment: In your JavaScript you can fetch the ID with $('.dialog_link').click(function(){ var Clicked_Link_ID = $(this).attr('id'); ...

Comment: I have now created unique id:s using the uniqid() function, I have printed them and they look good. They are also set on the link. I have added your javascriptcode but it's still the same.

I can see that a variable is created in the script, but is it used?
The attached file in main issue has been updated with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one item with the same id, an ID has to be unique.

Add some unique ID from your database results to the ID of your html link.

Then add a class "js_show_info" or the like to your link and attach your jQuery handler to this class.

```
$('.js_show_info').click()...
```

Comment: Setting a unique id is no problem. And I follow you on what you want to accomplish using the "js_show_info", but since I am very new to JavaScript I do not exactly know how to do it. Could you noobify it a bit more? :)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else already mentioned, you need to have unique IDs. Make a class dialog_link and assign IDs inside the while loop equal to a unique value, such as the SQL table row number of a given record.